# Convert iPhone 4 30-pin connector to iPhone 5 Lightning connector

Tags: iphone, lightning

I need a 30-pin (iPhone 4) to Lightning (iPhone 5) with a long cable (1m) between the 2 ends.

Does such thing exist?

Answer (score 1):

Apple sells a [Lightning to 30-pin adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD824ZM/A/lightning-to-30-pin-adapter-02-m?fnode=3c).

If you're okay with 3rd-party solution, [30-pin female to Lightning adapter](http://www.lightinthebox.com/30-pin-female-to-lightning-adapter-with-1m-cable-for-iphone-5-ipad-mini-and-ipod-touch-5_p461318.html)  could be closer to what you need, but there could be compatibility issues.

The kit includes this:

[image: image of 30-pin female to Lightning adapter]

to which you can add [Lightning 1m-extension cable](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Lightning-Extension-Cable-Apple-iPhone-White/dp/B00C2PDV98) which should get you from Lightning to 30-pin.

As far as I can see there is no single cable that does what you want.

Comment: Thanks Paul- I wanted a female 30pin end with a longer cable that ends in a lightning end. This is for a car ausio system that has a 30pin male end but I need to stretch the phone from there to the dashboard wher I can see the display (the connector is in a central console between the two front seats. Any suggestions?

Comment: The Apple connector is pathetically short. If it had a metre long cable between the 2 ends it would be perfect for my needs

Comment: I've updated my answer with a possible solution

Comment: The extension cable link is now dead.

Comment: unfortunately both 3rd party links are now dead